# CSS Selector Generation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing a problem while making a logic for automatic generation of CSS path of an element in a web page.

Use-Case: When a user clicks on any element on a web page, a css selector is generated automatically.

This works fine for scraping text when the next page is identical but problem occurs when the order of elements is changed. For example:

```
<html>
    ....
    <body>
          <div>ABC</div>
          <div>DEF
               <span>GHI</span>
               <ul>
                   <li>123abc</li>
                   <li>123abc</li>
                   <li>xyz</li>
               </ul>
          </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Suppose I generate a CSS selector for the 3rd li element containing "xyz" as

body > div:nthchild(2) > ul > li:nthchild(3)

Now if a page changes and new HTML is:

```
<html>
    ....
    <body>
          <div>ABC</div>
          <div>DEF
               <span>GHI</span>
               <ul>
                   <li>123abc</li>
                   <li>xyz</li>
               </ul>
          </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I use the same selector generated above (body > div:nthchild(2) > ul > li:nthchild(3)) and this returns me [null].

Keep in mind that the li elements don't have any classes, ids, attributes. They are just plain text containing li tags.

Currently I use the following properties to generate CSS selectors: tagname, id, classname and nth-child index.

Please help me!

Comment: So, basically, you're not looking for a css selector, but for a text content match? You could use `body > div:nthchild(2) > ul > li:last-child` for **this** precise example, but it would fail in many others. In this case, I can only see JS being able to find the element with the right text.

Comment: What exactly are you targeting?

Comment: @Mottie: I want to generate CSS selector for one page for a target text and then use this CSS selector for getting the same target text from 100s of other pages

Comment: So, could you use [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)?

Comment: @Mottie: Yes I can. I will explore this option. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the last one you can use :

```
body > div:nthchild(2) > ul > li:nth-last-child(1)
```

Comment: No, The element could be anywhere and not necessarily the last one.